# Won't allow me to save edits to appsscript.json

Tags: json, google-apps-script, ide, google-oauth, manifest

I'd like to access the name associated with a users google account to resolve a
`GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to people.people.get failed with error: The caller does not have permission to request "people/me". Request requires one of the following scopes: [profile]` error.

To do that, I'm attempting to include the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile scope as listed on Google's list of [OAuth 2.0 scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes). However, after editing the appsscript.json to manually include the scope, as outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests), and attempting to save, it does not work. It displays the "Saving project..." popup, but it never resolves and reloading the page resets appsscript.json without my changes. The scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo has the same response. There is no error message associated with this.

Here is my current file- have I missed something silly? Am I going about it wrong?

```
{
  "oauthScopes": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.names",
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "People",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "peopleapi"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "MYSELF"
  }
}
```

Comment: The `oauthScopes` value should be a array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Apps Script IDE / online Editor doesn't allow to save the project if any of the files have a syntax error. In the specific case of Apps Script project manifest (appsscript.json) this file should have a valid JSON and should have a specific structure.

The Apps Script project manifest structure is specified in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest.

---

In the specific case mentioned by the OP, the `oauthScopes` property should contain an Array or strings. Considering this, change

```
"oauthScopes": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.names",
```

by

```
"oauthScopes": [ "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.names" ],
```

Another typical error when manually editing the manifest is to forget to add a comma to separate two properties.