# Google App Script won't allow saving edits to appsscript.json

Tags: json, google-apps-script, syntax-error, google-oauth

I've written a Google App Script in a google sheet that requires access to gmail.
I want to limit that access to read only in gmail so that when I share this with others, to limit the scripts access and reduce the scary warning messages.

When I edit the appsscript.json file, the project never saves and doesn't throw a visible error.
I just see "Saving project..." until I refresh the page and lose the edits.

Below is my appscript.json I'm trying to save.

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"

  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly",
  ]

}
```

I've also tried without the comma after ...readlonly"

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"

  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"
  ]

}
```

If that's not possible, is there a way to do something similar to

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc 
 */
```

at the top of the code.gs to limit gmail to read only?

I followed the edit suggested here
([Won't allow me to save edits to appsscript.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73535604/wont-allow-me-to-save-edits-to-appsscript-json)) and it didn't make a difference.

I'm working in a corporate google instance and copied by code in my personal gmail and the first time I tried to save, briefly, saw a red error message about "Invalid changes (?) something..."  I tried to recreate the error message an was unable to.

Comment: Looks like you forget a comma after `"V8"`.

Comment: Edited the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73535604/wont-allow-me-to-save-edits-to-appsscript-json to make it a more general answer.